# Multiple HTML forms on one page with multiple stripe.js files?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I have multiple html POST forms on one page for Stripe..  The issue is I can only POST the last form on the page.  If i try submitting the former ones, it will not work and give me errors (on the front-end) due to the last form on the page not being filled out.

Eg forms on single page:

```
<%= form_for(@order, url: listing_orders_path([@listing, @listing_video]), html: {id: "payment_form"} ) do |form| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :name, "Your Name" %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <%= form.hidden_field :order_type, value: "video" %>
  <script

    src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/">

  </script>
    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="card-element">
        Credit or debit card
      </label>
      <div id="card-element" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
    </div>
      <br>
      <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.submit "Create Order"} %>
  </div>
  <span class="token"></span>
  <% end %>

<%= form_for(@order, url: listing_orders_path([@listing, @listing_video]), html: {id: "payment_form-a"} ) do |form| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :name, "Their Name" %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <%= form.hidden_field :order_type, value: "video" %>

  <script

    src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/">

  </script>
        <div class="form-row">
      <label for="card-element-a">
        Credit or debit card
      </label>
      <div id="card-element-a" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
    </div>
      <br>
      <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.submit "Create Order" %>
  </div>
  <span class="token"></span>
  <% end %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "stripe" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "stripe-a" %>
```

Here is the stripe.js file:

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxx');

var elements = stripe.elements();

var style = {
  base: {
    color: '#32325d',
    lineHeight: '24px',
    fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
    fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
    fontSize: '16px',
    '::placeholder': {
      color: '#aab7c4'
    }
  },
  invalid: {
    color: '#fa755a',
    iconColor: '#fa755a'
  }
};

var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

card.mount('#card-element');

card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});

var form = document.getElementById('payment_form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Inform the user if there was an error
      var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
      // Send the token to your server
      stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
    }
  });
});

  function stripeTokenHandler(token) {

    var form = document.getElementById('payment_form');
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    form.submit();
  }

  function addFieldToForm(form, token, field) {
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', "user[card_" + field + "]");
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.card[field]);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
  }
```

The stripe-a.js file is the same but with `payment-form` changed to `payment-form-a` and `card-element` changed to `card-element-a`.

I tried using a `value: "payment_form"` within the submit button but it didn't differentiate it (i read this would help on SO)

Anyone have any suggestions on allowing multiple HTML POST forms on the same page and allowing the form that is submitted to submit only, and all of the others not interfere?

Comment: Is there any way to integrate the multiple forms into one javascript file? Where maybe is cycles through to see which ones submitted, or some other ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with multiple forms on the page? Do you have multiple products one can buy. fwiw, Stripe only lets you create one card Element on a given page. One thing you could do is  setup different `<button>`s and depending upon the button clicked, user purchases a different product, etc

Comment: @duck i got it working with javascript functions.  It works so far and each form will allow a payment to go through.  I assume once one function is clicked, the others are unloaded? Not sure, but it works.  Haven't found it not working yet but will test it again this week to be 100% sure about itp